# Transforming a DataFrame in Julia using `@transform`

Tags: iterator, dataframe, julia

I am experimenting with Julia's DataFrame and I came across the following problem related to iterators on the DataFrame object. If I define a DataFrame and apply built-in functions on it, there is apparent iteration on the DataFrame's rows:

```
using DataFrames, DataFramesMeta
df = DataFrame(a = [1, 2, 3], b =[6, 7, 8])

@transform(df, mt = sin(:a) .* cos(:b))
```

However if I try a similar pattern using my own function, in this case MyType's constructor function, say,

```
type MyType
    a::Float64
    b::Float64
    function MyType(in1, in2)
        new(3 * in1, 2 * in2)
    end
end
```

it does not work:

```
@transform(df, mt = MyType(:a, :b))
```

gives the error message:

```
LoadError: MethodError: `convert` has no method matching convert(::Type{Float64}, ::DataArrays.DataArray{Int64,1})
This may have arisen from a call to the constructor Float64(...),
since type constructors fall back to convert methods.
Closest candidates are:
  call{T}(::Type{T}, ::Any)
  convert(::Type{Float64}, !Matched::Int8)
  convert(::Type{Float64}, !Matched::Int16)
  ...
while loading In[107], in expression starting on line 1

 in ##12728 at /Users/szalmaf/.julia/v0.4/DataFramesMeta/src/DataFramesMeta.jl:45
 in anonymous at /Users/szalmaf/.julia/v0.4/DataFramesMeta/src/DataFramesMeta.jl:147
 in transform at /Users/szalmaf/.julia/v0.4/DataFramesMeta/src/DataFramesMeta.jl:122
```

which suggests that I should add another constructor to MyType that can handle `DataArray`s. Is there another, more idiomatic way of applying `@transform` or is there any another way that can handle this map or transformation as a oneliner?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, a type constructor can only return a single instance, but the `transform` operator is a vector operation. You can write a function to wrap the object construction:

```
function makeMT(a, b)
  [MyType(a[i],b[i]) for i = 1:size(a,1)]
end

@transform(df, mt = makeMT(:a, :b))
```

which yields:

```
3x3 DataFrame
| Row | a | b | mt               |
|-----|---|---|------------------|
| 1   | 1 | 6 | MyType(3.0,12.0) |
| 2   | 2 | 7 | MyType(6.0,14.0) |
| 3   | 3 | 8 | MyType(9.0,16.0) |
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't fit your one-liner criterion.

Comment: I want to do something like transform(df, mt = MyType(df[:,:a], df[:,:b])). Note the colons! That is, the `mt` should reflect the corresponding row's `a` and `b`.

Comment: I misunderstood the first time; hopefully my edited answer gets you closer to finding a suitable solution.

Comment: Yes, your `makeMT(a,b)` is really close to the solution. I tried to strip the problem down completely to make it clear. My additional aim is to make make it generic in the sense that it works for any MyType and also any number of arguments in that generic MyType, i.e. MyType2(a, b, c). If you have any suggestions for that, it is very welcome. Thanks.

Comment: In the meantime I was looking at the workings of methods and macros in DataFramesMeta and an earlier than the current version contained a `@byrow` macro, see `https://github.com/JuliaStats/DataFramesMeta.jl/issues/24`, which, I suspect, did what I need here but I don't see why the package was rolled back and left out the`@byrow` feature.

Comment: I suppose some clever macro version of this would do what you want: `df[:mt] = DataArray(Any, size(df,1));
for f in eachrow(df);
  f[:mt] = MyType(f[:a], f[:b]);
end`, where I'm hijacking `;` to indicate line breaks. My macro knowledge isn't up to that yet.

Comment: The `@byrow` macro looks like it would replace my explicit iteration, but you'd still have to create the new column first with `df[:mt] = DataArray(Any, size(df,1))`

Answer (score 1):

If you pass multiple arrays to `map`, then during the nth iteration it will pass the nth element from *each* array as arguments to the function. So:

```
 @transform(df, mt = map(MyType, :a, :b))
```

yields:

```
3x3 DataFrame
| Row | a | b | mt               |
|-----|---|---|------------------|
| 1   | 1 | 6 | MyType(3.0,12.0) |
| 2   | 2 | 7 | MyType(6.0,14.0) |
| 3   | 3 | 8 | MyType(9.0,16.0) |
```